# React Javascript trouble with passing user input onchange to a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm running into a problem when passing down down a method from a parent component to a child component. The parent, FilterableProductTable has a state called filterText. FilterableProductTable renders a child component SearchBar, and passes down a function called handleChange as a prop. SearchBar calls this function onChange, so that I can transfer the user input from SearchBar to the filterText state in FilterableProductTable.

The problem I'm running into is filterText gets updated one increment too late. I logged filterText to the console and I logged the value of the user input, both in my handleChange function:

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ filterText: event.target.value });
    console.log(event.target.value + "value");
    console.log(this.state.filterText + "state");
}
```

and the output I get in the console is:

//user input=a.

a value

state

//user input=ab

ab value

a state

//user input =a, because b was deleted(backspace key)

a value

ab state

-----As you can see the state is one increment behind the event.target.value. I'm not sure how to fix this. Below are my two functions. If someone could help me see what I'm doing wrong that would be great.

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    placeholder="Search.."
                    onChange={this.props.handleChange}
                ></input>
                <br />
                <input type="checkbox" /> Only show items in stock
            </form>
        );
    }
}

class FilterableProductTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            filterText: "",
            inStockOnly: false,
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ filterText: event.target.value });
        console.log(event.target.value + " value");
        console.log(this.state.filterText + " state");
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.filterText + " render");
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBar handleChange={this.handleChange} />
                <ProductTable
                    products={this.props.products}
                    filterText={this.state.filterText}
                    inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `setting` state in React is an `asynchronous` operation and won't be affected immediately. you need to use the `setState` callback for your check like this:

```
handleChange(event){
    this.setState({filterText:event.target.value}, () => {
      console.log(event.target.value+ ' value');
      console.log(this.state.filterText+ ' state');
    });
}
```